# Sobre 'x.count()' en un dataset

Tags: python, pandas

Estoy trabajando en `python` y sus respectivas librerías importadas, como **pandas, numpy**, entre otros, y debo utilizar el valor de una de las siguientes sentencias...

```
data_s1[['VARIABLE']].count()
```

el cual lee una columna de un dataset, pero al utilizarlo, este entrega el siguiente resultado...

```
VARIABLE    110405
dtype: float64
```

De esto, sólo me sirve el 110405 y no lo que está en su segunda línea, y este número lo debo usar en otras líneas, más adelante en el código.

¿Alguien conoce algún método o forma de poder usar el "count" sin que se considere el dtype y resto?.

De antemano, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

```py
data_s1[['VARIABLE']].count().values
```

retorna un vector tipo ***numpy.array*** con el valor que buscas, es decir:

```py
array([110405])
```

Usa `dir( data_s1[['VARIABLE']].count() )` para explorar otras funciones-incluidas que puedes aplicar a tu "variable".

Answer (score 0):

Mientras hacía otras cosas en mi trabajo en código python, se me ocurrió utilizar la opción `int()` para la expresión `data_s1[['VARIABLE']].count()` y luego de solicitar un 
`print( int(data_s1[['VARIABLE']].count()) )` 
finalmente python sólo considere el número, que era lo que buscaba.

Bueno, independiente de que pude encontrar la respuesta, de todos modos, si alguien conocer otra forma, que lo escriba, así existe más opciones o alternativas de solución a esta pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

El problema si lo he interpretado correctamente no es cómo convertir la salida a un entero, es simplemente que indizas incorrectamente para lo que quieres obtener:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({"Col1": [1, 2, 6, 8],
                   "Col2": [3, 4, 8, 4]}
)
```

> ```
> >>> df
>
>    Col1  Col2
> 0     1     3
> 1     2     4
> 2     6     8
> 3     8     4
> ```

Hay una gran **diferencia entre pasar el nombre de la columna en forma de  cadena como índice a pasar una lista con cadenas**.

Si pasamos una cadena al indizar, siendo ésta el nombre válido de una columna, nos retorna dicha columna sin más, una `Serie`:

> ```
> >>> type(df["Col1"])
> pandas.core.series.Series
> ```

y al aplicar **`pandas.Series.count()` nos retorna un entero** como cabe esperar (que es lo que buscas):

> ```
> >>> df["Col2"].count()
> 4
> ```

En cambio, cunado pasas una lista, lo que se retorna es un DataFrame con las columnas seleccionadas de la lista en el mismo orden:

> ```
> >>> type(df[["Col1"]])
> pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
> ```

Al aplicar **`pandas.DataFrame.count()` el resultado es una Serie**, resultado de aplicar `count` a cada columna:

```
>>> df[["Col1", "Col2"]].count()

Col1    4
Col2    4
dtype: int64
```

Por lo tanto, si quieres aplicar `count` a una columna no uses

```
data_s1[['VARIABLE']].count()
```

usa:

```
data_s1['VARIABLE'].count()
```

---

En referencia a tu propia solución a la pregunta:

```
int(df[["VARIABLE"]].count())
```

funciona (aunque no es la forma de hacerlo, porque indizando bien te evitas este paso extra) porque aplicas el casting a una serie de un solo elemento, pero fallará si intentamos hacer lo mismo sobre una de varios elementos:

> ```
> >>> int(df[["Col1", "Col2"]].count())
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<ipython-input-67-fb0ea1f72214>", line 1, in <module>
>     int(df[["Col1", "Col2"]].count())
> TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>
> ```

Si en estos casos quieres deshacerte de la serie, puedes hacer varias cosas:

- Desempaquetar directamente:

  > ```
  > >>> col1_count, col2_count = df[["Col1", "Col2"]].count()
  > >>> col1_count
  > 4
  > ```
- Convertir a un array NumPy:

  > ```
  > >>> df[["Col1", "Col2"]].count().to_numpy()
  > array([4, 4])
  > ```
- Convertir a una lista:

  > ```
  > >>> df[["Col1", "Col2"]].count().to_list()
  > [4, 4]
  > ```